# Relationship between CPO and the number of constraints

Tags: scheduling, cp

I am kind of new into CP for scheduling problems and it seems to work very good for the type of problems I am facing in my PhD.

However, I am facing now a very complex problem of a job shop with assemblies that I have programmed using CPO. Gaps are significantly high (around 65%) and I am trying to "help" the solver find the optimal solution by transforming problem information into constraints.

Therefore, as in MILP, I try constraining the problem (more) by limiting certain solutions: for instance, always schedule certain jobs before other ones when they are assigned in the same machine.

In doing so, (especially in the largest instance where the number of variables is very high), that adds up so many constraints to the model and seems to make it "harder" for the solver to close the GAP although now the number of feasible solutions is lower. I guess it has to do with the way the solver "attacks" the combinatorial problem.

I know this might sound "obvious", but I would like to know exactly why and how can I then help the solver close the GAP using problem information...

Thank you for your help in advance,

Javi

Answer (score 0):

In CP, even if the solver finds an optimal solution, the gap may stay at a high value a very long time. I mean a very very long time... If you really want the gap to converge to 0, you may be able to exploit some specific properties of your problem to compute a good lower bound.

Comment: Actually, after comparing results between a MILP and a CPO model, I have realized that the lower bound in the CPO model is extremely low compared to the optimal solution, that is, CPO is finding a very good solution but it thinks that it is still very far from the optimal when that's not the case. Any idea on how to improve the lower bound? I have read that adding redundant constraints may impact the lower bound...